# Remaining value in dynamically created input after sending it to server by clicking submit

Tags: javascript, php

I create a form with input and submit button in javascript. So in html file I don't have input tags.
If I create input tags in html, I can write:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="id" value="<?php echo $_POST["name"];?>">
```

and that works okay.

But I cannot write php code in javascript. Can I address to input value in php? I guess not.

I prefer to work in js, not ajax and etc.

Comment: *"But I cannot write php code in javascript."* - You can if it's embedded in (rather than referenced by) the PHP page.  (Well, you can use PHP *within* the JavaScript code block, to *produce* JavaScript code.  If that's what you meant.  It's not really clear.)  *"Can I address to input value in php?"* - It's not clear to me what you're asking.  *"I guess not."* - Oh, then did you have another question?  Please clarify.

Comment: I create form, input box and submit button in javascript. Then I put info in input box, click submit button, and the info is sent to server. When info is sent to server, info is deleted from input box.
I know how to remain it in input box, if I created input box in html file. But how can I remain it in input box when I create it in javascript?

Comment: If the page is posting a request to the server then the entire page context is lost.  What happens after that?  Is the server rendering a new page?  Even if it's the same page again?  Are you trying to *re-populate* the form with the previously submitted values?  Wherever/however you create the form elements, that's where you'd set those values.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  Please provide an example of the problem and indicate where specifically you're stuck.

Comment: "I prefer to work in js, not ajax and etc" - ajax IS javascript

Answer (score 0):

For my answer, I'm converting the POST to JSON with json_encode. This will allow javascript to read the data in the echo.

First, you will want to convert the $_POST to json.

```
<?php
    $formData = json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

Next you will want to echo that into a javascript variable:

```
<script>
    const postedForm = <?php echo $formData;?>;
</script>
```

Last you will want to get that value and put it into your field. Here is a test field as an example.

This line **postedForm["fieldName"] || ""** Basically will check to see if fieldName exists in the object called postedForm, if not it fills it in with an empty value.

```
<script>    
    let field = document.createElement("input");
    field.type = "text";
    field.value = postedForm["fieldName"] || "";
    document.body.appendChild(field)
</script>
```